# Extracting identifiers without matching files in a folder

Tags: r, substring, stringr

How to extract the identifiers which do not have corresponding files being generated?

Identifiers which are given as input for generation fo files:

```
fileIden <- c('a-1','a-2','a-3','b-1','b-2','c-1','d-1','d-2','d-3','d-4')
```

Checking the files generated:

```
files <- list.files(".")

files
# [1] "a-2.csv" "a-3.csv" "b-1.csv" "c-1.csv" "d-3.csv"

# Generated here for reproducibility.
# files <- c("a-2.csv", "a-3.csv", "b-1.csv", "c-1.csv", "d-3.csv")
```

Expected files if all the process is completely successful

```
fileExp <- paste(fileIden, ".csv", sep = "")
# [1] "a-1.csv" "a-2.csv" "a-3.csv" "b-1.csv" "b-2.csv" "c-1.csv" "d-1.csv" "d-2.csv" "d-3.csv" "d-4.csv"
```

Any expected files are missing?

```
fileMiss <- fileExp[!fileExp %in% files]
# [1] "a-1.csv" "b-2.csv" "d-1.csv" "d-2.csv" "d-4.csv"
```

Expected output

```
# "a-1" "b-2" "d-1" "d-2" "d-4"
```

I am sure that there is an easy process directly to get the above output without creating the files: `fileExp`, `fileMiss`. Could you please guide me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
fileIden <- c('a-1','a-2','a-3','b-1','b-2','c-1','d-1','d-2','d-3','d-4')
file <- c("a-2.csv", "a-3.csv" ,"b-1.csv", "c-1.csv", "d-3.csv")


setdiff(fileIden, trimws(gsub("\\.csv","", file)))
```

**Another approach:**

```
setdiff(fileIden, stringr::str_extract(file,"(.*)(?=\\.csv)"))
```

**Logic**:

`setdiff` finds the difference between two vectors, `gsub` replaces the ".csv" with nothing , we club them together to find the difference between those vectors.

**Output:**

```
#[1] "a-1" "b-2" "d-1" "d-2" "d-4"
```

Comment: @Prradep So, if you are using a dot, its required as it has a special meaning, In this case however it doesn't make any difference, but in other case it would. Hence its a right practice to use \\ before "dot" to match the "dot" literally.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer in sometime after looking at other `stringr` based approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

a less elegant approach

```
result <- ifelse(fileIden %in% substr(file, 1, 3), "", fileIden)
result[result != ""]
```